# Showing PostgreSQL table comments in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, arcgis-pro

[Comments](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-comment.html) are a useful way to annotate database objects such as fields and tables in PostgreSQL. A comment on a table is written like this:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE table IS 'QGIS has no issues reading table-level comments from PostgreSQL.';
```

They show up as comments when a PostgreSQL layer is loaded in QGIS, as evidenced in the Information pane:

[image: QGIS information pane screenshot]

QGIS also shows field-level comments in the Field pane:

[image]

My question is, does ArcGIS Pro have the same capability? When I load the layer there, the 'table metadata' shows up as blank:

[image: ArcGIS doesn't show the metadata]

I might not be looking in the correct place, but I'm not seeing where else it might be hiding.

Alternatively, is there another method to include PostgreSQL comments when loading layers into ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, but it's possible to create a view from any table and write a field comment into a field by referencing where it is in the table. Hoping there's something better out there.

```
select pk,geom,col_description('schema.table'::regclass::oid, 1) from schema.table limit 1
```